# best regression function for multinomial regression

Tags: r, regression, glm, multinomial

When using the glm function: which is the best distribution for multinomial regression --- is it "binomial"? If the glm function doesn't have an appropriate distribution for multinomial regression, which r package has a better function? Thank you!

Comment: In general it's better to frame questions as "how do I do X?" rather than "where do I find a package that does X?", since the latter is considered a "software recommendation" question and thus off-topic for Stack Overflow (even if the *answer* turns out to be "get package Y")

Comment: Thank you! I am pretty new to stack overflow so I didn't realize this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may try the `nnet::multinom()`
You can find the documentation at [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nnet/versions/7.3-15/topics/multinom).

Comment: I think the answer would be improved if you explained that `glm()` *can't* fit multinomial models and linked to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114194/can-multinomial-models-be-estimated-using-generalized-linear-model ...

Comment: Thank you @BenBolker. Your comment was very helpful!